# Saxon's Error Code format?

Tags: json, error-handling, sublimetext3, build-process, saxon

I'm using Sublime Text and I just wanted to know where I should look for Saxon's error code format.

For my project, I'm using the following JSON format to describe the build system I'm using:

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "[Kolcraft] Validate Feed",
            "file_regex": "",
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell_cmd": "xmllint --noout --schema src/ProductFeed5.6.xsd src/bv-kolcraft.xml",
            "selector": "source.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "[Contours] Validate Feed",
            "file_regex": "",
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell_cmd": "xmllint --noout --schema src/ProductFeed5.6.xsd src/bv-contours.xml",
            "selector": "source.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "[Kolcraft] Transform Export",
            "file_regex": "",
            "env": {
                "CLASSPATH": ".;backup/saxon9pe.jar;backup/saxon9-icu.jar;backup/saxon9-sql.jar;backup/saxon9pe-test.jar"
            },
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell_cmd": "java net.sf.saxon.Transform -o:src/bv-contours.xml -s:src/CONTOURS.xml -xsl:src/mrc2bv.xsl -xsltversion:2.0 -ext:on feedName=kolcraft -traceout:#out",
            "selector": "source.xml"
        },
        {
            "name": "[Contours] Transform Export",
            "file_regex": "",
            "env": {
                "CLASSPATH": ".;backup/saxon9pe.jar;backup/saxon9-icu.jar;backup/saxon9-sql.jar;backup/saxon9pe-test.jar"
            },
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell_cmd": "java net.sf.saxon.Transform -o:src/bv-kolcraft.xml -s:src/KOLCRAFT.xml -xsl:src/mrc2bv.xsl -xsltversion:2.0 -ext:on feedName=contoursbaby -traceout:#out",
            "selector": "source.xml"
        },
    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": [".*", "backup", "schema"]
        },
        {
            "path": "schema",
            "name": "Schema"
        }
    ]
}
```

What Sublime Text does to capture error output is use the `file_regex` field. It uses a [regular expression](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) rather than rely on any external listener program, or watch the `sys.stderr` stream from it's embedded Python interpreter.

I just want to be able to use the right regular expression for the build system, is all. Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like more info is needed. Do you have any example output or additional information that you can post?

Comment: I just need a regular expression that can capture the error messages Saxon gives.

Comment: Which error messages? XSLT compile time, XSLT run time, XSD validation errors... Without knowing what Sublime Text is, I'm afraid I really don't know what you're talking about. And in any case, the format of Saxon error messages depends on your ErrorListener. If you want to make the messages easily recognizable, the best way would be to write your own ErrorListener.

Comment: Sublime Text is a text editor, written in Python. Needless to say, I think a custom ErrorListener would be a bit overkill for capturing error messages in its context. I was hoping to only catch XSLT run time and compile time errors, is all.